# Is it possible to create a thread that calls a function from a different class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, function-pointers

I am working on a C++11 multithreated GUI program.

So I have the `DevTools` and `MainWindow` classes. I want to call a function that belongs to `DevTools` from a `MainWindow` clicked() event function. (All object definitions are created on the classes' definitions).

Function on `MainWindow` calls `Obtain_XY_Thread`:

```
void MainWindow::on_obtain_xy_clicked()
{
    DevTools.Obtain_XY_Thread();
}
```

So `DevTools::Obtain_XY_Thread()` is called and it creates a thread of `Obtain_XY` but what I really want is directly call `Obtain_XY`:

```
void DevTools::Obtain_XY_Thread()
{
    thread obtain_xy(&DevTools::Obtain_XY, *this);
    obtain_xy.detach();
}

void DevTools::Obtain_XY()
{
    for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
        //does something
    }
}
```

This works, but I don't think it's the correct approach. Is there any way to call `Obtain_XY` without having to create another function? How could I create the thread on `MainWindow::on_obtain_xy_clicked()` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was simply fixed by adding `std::thread`:

```
void MainWindow::on_obtain_xy_clicked()
{
    std::thread obtain_xy(&DevTools::Obtain_XY, &DevTools);
    obtain_xy.detach();
}
```

Comment: You don't need `class` here. You have moved equivalent code from `DevTools::Obtain_XY_Thread` to `MainWindow::on_obtain_xy_clicked`

Comment: How would that be done without a `class` ? I tried to not use it but I got the following error: " `must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'thread' in this scope` ", so I added it.

Comment: do you have something else visible to that scope named `thread`? Or use it's actual name, `std::thread`

Comment: Adding `std::thread` instead worked perfectly. I had tried `using namespace std;` but `thread` did not seem to be affected. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Do you have something else named `thread`, a function, a global variable, or a class member?

Comment: I don't, it's just the direct use of `thread` from the `<thread>` header file.